# How to read ajax parameters in asp mvc model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have angular service:

```
statistics.factory('getData', function ($http) {
return {
    result: function (url, date) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                date: date
            }
        });
    }
};});
```

This service send to MVC controller date parameter.

I want to see the data parameter in MVC Model Bidned.

I tried:

```
 public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        var date = request["date"];
        var date1 = request.Form.Get("date");
        var date3 = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);
        var requestFromPost = date3.ReadToEnd();

    }
```

but I always got null value.

This is my model binder:

```
public class DataBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var date = request.QueryString["date"];

        return date;
    }
```

and action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetStatisticsData([ModelBinder(typeof(DataBinder))] DataA dataA)

}
```

Comment: You might want to check the query string: `var date = request.QueryString["date"];`

Comment: can you check "date" is not undefined in ajax parameter? -

Comment: of course, when I have action like this: 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetStatisticsData(string date)

} 
it's working proper

Comment: What is `null` exactly, the `var request` or the request to get `var date`?

Answer (score 0):

For your first `BindModel` implementation you were not returning any object so it is not valid as it is and the second one is valid at least but you are trying to get the `date` value from wrong collection it should be `Form` not `QueryString` and also returning `object` when your binding in the Action expecting type `DataA`. So following is what it should be (excluding necessary checking and localization) :

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var date = DateTime.Parse(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["date"]);
    return new DataA 
    {
        SomeDate = date
    };
}
```

Also I posted a solution based on your question [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1LqNKP) you will see it running. I used jquery instead of angular to make the answer quickly but the request is same as $http. Hope it helps you and ask if any more questions.